# Unseen questions for each favorite tag

Tags: feature-request

I find myself clicking each of my favorite tags on the front page and opening a new tab with that tag sorted by Newest just to see if any new questions have come in that aren't on the front page right now.

It would be useful if I knew at a glance that new questions had come in for a particular favorite. The favorite tag could have an "unread" color applied to it, or a count of unseen messages could appear next to it or something similar.

Yes, I know this requires some more tracking in the DB.

Comment: You mean like if you could subscribe to a tag and something would update you when new questions are posted using that tag?

Comment: If you're referring to the email features, I'm aware of them. I'd like to review the front page when I have the inclination and see quickly if favorites are available to read or if I should wade through the first few pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the URL of a search request to "hack" yourself a solution, then save it as a bookmark.

So for php and java it would be:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q="php" or "java"
```

You can add as many tags as you like. If you don't want to type it out by hand, you can use the search box and enter

```
"tag1" or "tag2" or "tag3"
```

then hit the "Newest" bar and copy & paste the generated URL.

Comment: beware, you're relying on the search to auto-map your search terms to tags. easier to use tags in the first place.

Comment: While this will show me more questions that I want to see, it's not telling me that there are new questions for each tag. I want to know that new questions have come in for a given tag.

Answer (score 1):

So long as you have marked favorite tags, and are logged in, the homepage will adapt to you:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/

beyond that you can combine tags in the address bar using `or`, like so:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+or+php?sort=newest`

This is going to be hellaciously useless for busy tags, though.

Comment: It's just that the "interesting" tab doesn't work all to well. For example, of the questions shown to me right now, there are a total of 5 that have favorite tags of mine, 3 of which are at the very bottom. All the rest are basically uninteresting and I can't see any correlation with my top answer tags. Why can't it just show me recent unanswered questions from my favorite tags?

Comment: @eye read the blog entry closely

Comment: I understand why it comes up the way it does, I am just saying that it doesn't fit my preferences at all. The whole notion of only using the last 3000 questions totally disqualifies most of those that I'd be interested in (there's a lot more people asking about c++ than about actionscript), isn't there some way to take this into consideration? Doesn't the current system disfavor anyone with favorites that aren't especially common?

Comment: I have to agree with @EyeSeeEm. The new interesting tab isn't improving my situation. Also, surprisingly, it doesn't address my original issue. I want to know exactly that there are new questions for each favorite tag.

Comment: @ohm then you need to subscribe to them via email, or on the http://stackexchange.com/tagsets -- it does *exactly* what you want. Full stop.